# Subtract value in previous row for each section of a data frame that corresponds to a certain ID in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a data frame with three columns:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c(101,101,101,102,102,102,102,104,104), 
Year=c(2005,2006,2007,1998,1999,2000,2001,2012,2013),
AnnualSpending=c(94.50,87.63,44.95,65.37,44.22,25.64,125.78,250.87,100))

   ID Year AnnualSpending
1 101 2005          94.50
2 101 2006          87.63
3 101 2007          44.95
4 102 1998          65.37
5 102 1999          44.22
6 102 2000          25.64
7 102 2001         125.78
8 104 2012         250.87
9 104 2013         100.00
```

How can I subtract the previous value of AnnualSpending and add the result to a new column so that the first row corresponding to each ID is always 0?

```
changeFromPrevious
0
-6.87
-42.68
0
-21.15
-18.58
100.14
0
-150.87
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(changeFromPrevious = AnnualSpending - lag(AnnualSpending, 
                                                     default = AnnualSpending[1]))

     # A tibble: 9 × 4
     ID  Year AnnualSpending changeFromPrevious
  <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>              <dbl>
1   101  2005          94.50               0.00
2   101  2006          87.63              -6.87
3   101  2007          44.95             -42.68
4   102  1998          65.37               0.00
5   102  1999          44.22             -21.15
6   102  2000          25.64             -18.58
7   102  2001         125.78             100.14
8   104  2012         250.87               0.00
9   104  2013         100.00            -150.87
```

Comment: OP wants zeros for the first row when a new ID begins.

Comment: I edited your answer to match the output. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ave` and `diff`

```
> changeFromPrevious <- ave(df$AnnualSpending, df$ID, FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x)))
> data.frame(changeFromPrevious)
  changeFromPrevious
1               0.00
2              -6.87
3             -42.68
4               0.00
5             -21.15
6             -18.58
7             100.14
8               0.00
9            -150.87
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew about ave but wasn't familiar with the diff function. Glad to have this added to my repertoire.

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` equivalent:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, changeFromPrevious := AnnualSpending - shift(AnnualSpending, 
                                                       fill = AnnualSpending[1]), by = ID]

df

    ID Year AnnualSpending changeFromPrevious
1: 101 2005          94.50               0.00
2: 101 2006          87.63              -6.87
3: 101 2007          44.95             -42.68
4: 102 1998          65.37               0.00
5: 102 1999          44.22             -21.15
6: 102 2000          25.64             -18.58
7: 102 2001         125.78             100.14
8: 104 2012         250.87               0.00
9: 104 2013         100.00            -150.87
```