# Backfilling Rows Based on Max Conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataset that looks like this in R:

```
name = c("john", "john", "john", "alex", "alex", "peter", "peter", "peter", "peter")
year = c(2010, 2011, 2015, 2014, 2016, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
age = c(21, 21, 21, 55, 55, 61, 61, 61, 61)

problem_data = data.frame(name, year, age)

   name year age
1  john 2010  21
2  john 2011  21
3  john 2015  21
4  alex 2014  55
5  alex 2016  55
6 peter 2010  61
7 peter 2011  61
8 peter 2012  61
9 peter 2013  61
```

In this dataset, the age of each person at the last recorded year has been erroneously inserted at each row. For example - in reality:

- Peter was 61 in 2013
- Peter was 60 in 2012
- Peter was 59 in 2011
- Peter was 58 in 2010

Sometimes years are missing - as a result:

- Alex was 55 in 2016
- Alex was 53 in 2014

I am trying to research a way in R that can handle such a task. I have been trying to combine "cumulative group differences" and "max row conditions" - but I am not sure how these concepts can be combined together to achieve this:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237345/subtract-value-in-previous-row-for-each-section-of-a-data-frame-that-corresponds

library(dplyr)

new_data = problem_data %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(real_age= age - lag(age, default = age[1]))
```

Bur this approach has made everyone's age as 0!

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   name [3]
  name   year   age real_age
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 john   2010    21        0
2 john   2011    21        0
3 john   2015    21        0
4 alex   2014    55        0
5 alex   2016    55        0
6 peter  2010    61        0
7 peter  2011    61        0
8 peter  2012    61        0
9 peter  2013    61        0
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by 'name', use `complete` to get the missing 'year', `fill` the `NA` elements in 'year', 'age' with previous non-NA values,  subtract the 'age' from the sequence of group index

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
problem_data %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    complete(year = full_seq(year, period = 1)) %>% 
    fill(year, age, .direction = "downup") %>%
    mutate(real_age= age - (row_number() - 1)) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just a question - your code does not reference the "year" variable. How is it able to take into consideration "missing years"?

Comment: Thank you! I notice now there are NA's in some of the ages?

Comment: I guess I can just use na.omit() to remove these intermediate rows?

Comment: @antonoyaro8 i updated.  can you try now

Comment: @antonoyaro8 do you want the output with all the full years or just only the years in the initial data after the computation

Answer (score 2):

Do you need this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
problem_data %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  complete(., year = first(year):last(year), fill = list(freq = 0)) %>%
  arrange(-year, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(real_age = ifelse(row_number()>1,  last(age)-row_number()+1,  last(age))) %>% 
  drop_na() # optional
```

```
  name   year   age real_age
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 alex   2016    55       55
2 alex   2014    55       53
3 john   2015    21       21
4 john   2011    21       17
5 john   2010    21       16
6 peter  2013    61       61
7 peter  2012    61       60
8 peter  2011    61       59
9 peter  2010    61       58
```