# R: Adding Missing Rows to a Dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am working with the R.

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
id = c("john", "john", "john", "john","john", "james", "james", "james", "james", "james")
year = c(2010,2011, 2014, 2016,2017, 2013, 2016, 2017, 2018,2020)
var = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
my_data = data.frame(id, year, var)

> my_data
      id year var
1   john 2010   1
2   john 2011   1
3   john 2014   1
4   john 2016   1
5   john 2017   1
6  james 2013   1
7  james 2016   1
8  james 2017   1
9  james 2018   1
10 james 2020   1
```

As we can see, there are some missing years (i.e. non-consecutive years) in this dataset - **for each ID, I am trying to add rows corresponding to these missing years and assign the "var" variable as "0" in these rows.**

As an example, this would look something like this for the first ID:

```
    id year var
1 john 2010   1
2 john 2011   1
3 john 2012   0
4 john 2013   0
5 john 2014   1
6 john 2015   0
7 john 2016   1
8 john 2017   1
```

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74365569/backfilling-rows-based-on-max-conditions-in-r

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    complete(year = full_seq(year, period = 1)) %>% 
    fill(year, var, .direction = "downup") %>%
    mutate(var=  0 ) %>%
   ungroup
```

But this is not giving the desired result - as we can see, rows have been deleted and all values of "var" have been replaced with 0:

```
 A tibble: 16 x 3
   id     year   var
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 james  2013     0
 2 james  2014     0
 3 james  2015     0
 4 james  2016     0
 5 james  2017     0
 6 james  2018     0
 7 james  2019     0
 8 james  2020     0
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would include the `fill` argument in your `complete` function. There you can specify in a named list what you want to include as values for missing combinations.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  complete(year = full_seq(year, period = 1), fill = list(var = 0)) %>%
  ungroup
```

**Output**

```
   id     year   var
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 james  2013     1
 2 james  2014     0
 3 james  2015     0
 4 james  2016     1
 5 james  2017     1
 6 james  2018     1
 7 james  2019     0
 8 james  2020     1
 9 john   2010     1
10 john   2011     1
11 john   2012     0
12 john   2013     0
13 john   2014     1
14 john   2015     0
15 john   2016     1
16 john   2017     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data.frame with all year's and id's, then do a `full_join` with the original data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

expand_grid(id = unique(my_data$id),year = min(my_data$year):max(my_data$year)) %>% 
  full_join(my_data) %>% 
  replace_na(replace = list(var = 0))
```

Comment: @ Vinícius Félix : Thank you so much for your answer! This is a very clever use of "expand.grid" - I did not know it can be applied here! Do you know if this approach will scale well to larger datasets? ( I know that sometimes this is problematic with the expand.grid() function). Thank you so much!